# How can I return ScopeIdentity in a query of two Insert statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here I am inserting values into two columns but now I want to both declared values which is created just now:

```
Declare @ClientCompanyId int, @PersonId int

INSERT INTO ClientCompany (CompanyName) 
VALUES ('WebDunia')

SELECT @ClientCompanyId = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 

INSERT INTO Person (ClientCompanyId, Company, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, State, Country, Zip, HomePhone, WorkPhone, CellPhone, Fax, EmailId, Website)
VALUES (@ClientCompanyId, 'Google', 'Chicago', 'USA', 'Norway', 'ALASKA', 'CANADA', '12345', 12345678912, 12345, 56454, 'Fax', 'Email', 'Website')
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS PersonId
```

I want `PersonId` and `ClientCompanyId` at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another variable set, same as you use for `@ClientCompanyId`

```
Declare @ClientCompanyId int,
        @PersonId int
 INSERT INTO ClientCompany(CompanyName) VALUES     ('Google')
 SELECT @ClientCompanyId=SCOPE_IDENTITY() 

Insert into Person (ClientCompanyId,Company,AddressLine1, AddressLine2, 
                    City, State, Country, Zip, HomePhone, WorkPhone, 
                    CellPhone, Fax, EmailId, Website)                                  
Values(@ClientCompanyId,'Google','Chicago','USA','Norway',             
      'ALASKA','CANADA','12345',12345678912,12345,56454,'Fax',
       'Email','Website')

SELECT @ClientCompanyId, @PersonId=SCOPE_IDENTITY()     <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<**Here**
```

Comment: but it is not returning value of both id's

Comment: so you want to return both @ClientCompanyId, PersonId then see edit. You just simple see the Last Line of Answer here

Answer (score 1):

why not just replicate what you do with `@ClientCompanyID` with @PersonID  after the 2nd insert?

i.e. the line `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as PersonId` should read `SELECT @PersonID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()`   Then both variables will have values set.

I don't know in which context this sql runs, but if you need both values out, you could either select them - or in the case of a stored procedure have them as out parameters.

Comment: Can You please Explain complete Query

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO ClientCompany (CompanyName)
OUTPUT Inserted.ID
VALUES ('Google'), ('Microsoft')
```

It will return a list of all the inserted ids, I'm assuming your id column is ID.